# Reading a string inside a specific character using python

Tags: python, string, search, printing, character

I recently started learning programming, and now I'm using python to data filtering. My question is: How do I get a string inside a specific character? for example, in the text file I have something like this:

`5d:6g:9h:5t:7a:45;33:12:5B:9J;70;9C;89;85:4B:38:16:9B:45:56:85:`

and I want the string inside the 10th character `; ;`, or the 15th `: :`

I have read the txt file I've gotten some information, but this part in specfic I cound't figure out. Here's what I have so far:

```
import zipfile

arq = zipfile.ZipFile('DSts.zip')

for file in arq.namelist():
    print(file)
    f = arq.open(file) 
    Lines = f.readlines()
    for line in Lines:
        print(f'{line[11:16]}')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that you can integrate into your code. You'd be applying it to every line you read (or every line you think needs to be parsed like this),

```
def get_substring(input_string, delim, nth, delims):
    ''' Returns the substring between the nth character
            delim in the string and next such character; 
            delims is a list of all delimiters to account for '''

    # Indices of all occurences of delims
    idx_delims = [i for i, x in enumerate(input_string) if x in delims]
    # Retrieve the index of nth delim
    idx_nth = idx_delims[nth-1]
    # Find the index of the nth+1 delim
    idx_nth_p1 = input_string.index(delim, idx_nth+1)
    # Return the substring between those two positions
    return input_string[idx_nth+1:idx_nth_p1]

orig_string = '5d:6g:9h:5t:7a:45;33:12:5B:9J;70;9C;89;85:4B:38:16:9B:45:56:85:'

print(orig_string)

# All delimiters
delims = [':', ';']

# Substring between 10th and 11th :
str_1 = get_substring(orig_string, ';', 10, delims)
print(str_1)
# Substring between 15th and 16th ;
str_2 = get_substring(orig_string, ':', 15, delims)
print(str_2)
```

This function extracts all the characters that are considered delimiters from the input string. Then it finds the Nth delimiter as requested, and the next delimiter in the original string. It returns the string that's in between the two.

In reality, this should have some checking functionality, and relevant warnings, even exception throws (e.g. whether the `delim` exists, and if it's at the requested `nth` position). Also, it could be written more concisely, I made it longer for readability and understanding. Finally, you should remove the print statements in the final version.

---

Update: This is minimal code that demonstrates the integration. You can test it out standalone, then use the reading and postprocessing approach instead of `open` and `readlines` in your original code. There's nothing wrong with either but:

- `open` clause needs a `close` and `with open` provides you a `close` behind the scenes even if things crash.
- `readlines` reads the whole file at ones. I often work with files that are large, so I'm used to sparing the RAM and processing line by line. It's up to you, and the problem you're working on.

So here is the example:

```
def get_substring(input_string, delim, nth, delims):
    ''' Returns the substring between the nth character
            delim in the string and next such character; 
            delims is a list of all delimiters to account for '''

    # Indices of all occurences of delims
    idx_delims = [i for i, x in enumerate(input_string) if x in delims]
    # Retrieve the index of nth delim
    idx_nth = idx_delims[nth-1]
    # Find the index of the nth+1 delim
    idx_nth_p1 = input_string.index(delim, idx_nth+1)
    # Return the substring between those two positions
    return input_string[idx_nth+1:idx_nth_p1]


# All delimiters
delims = [':', ';']

all_substrings = []
with open('testfile.txt', 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        # Remove the leading and trailing whitespace
        line = line.strip()
        temp_str = get_substring(line, ':', 2, delims)
        all_substrings.append(temp_str)

print(all_substrings)
```

The code clears the trailing newline with `strip()` and it appends all the substrings to a list.

One note: the way you described your problem, it seemed to me like you wanted to match a specific delimiter at a position that is a count of all delimiters i.e. for this `5d:6g:9h:5t:7a:45;33:12:` the delimiter `;` would be the 6th delimiter, so the call turns to `(line, ';', 6, delims)`. Let me know if this is not the case, but consider adjusting it yourself for practice. This means the call you mentioned in the comment should be just like here, `(line, ':', 2, delims)`. Because `:` is the second delimiter. Also keep in mind that Python indexing starts with 0, so this is actually position 1 in the `idx_delims` list.

Finally, this is a minimal input file to test with:

```
5d:6g:9h:5t:7a:45;33:12:5B:9J;70;9C;89;85:4B:38:16:9B:45:56:85:
5d:6g:9h:4t:7a:45;33:12:5B:9J;70;9C;89;85:4B:38:16:9B:45:56:85:
3d:7g:9i:5t:7a:45;33:12:5B:9J;70;9C;89;85:4B:38:16:9B:45:56:85:
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried including it to my code but it didn't work. So as I'm reading a text file with multiples lines, I would have to check every line in the file, right? So that's what I did: I put the string "orig_string" and "str_1 inside" the loop like this: (The function "get_substring" was above the lines that opened the txt file): 


--> for line in Lines:
        orig_string = line
        str_1 = get_substring(orig_string, ';', 2, delims)
        print(str_1) <---.


But it's not working, and this error appears: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @ElleOliver Updated the answer, let me know if it's cleaner now.

Comment: Try it out, and if stuck, post some more details about your file (is it only the type of entries you posted? Does it have headers?)

Comment: Added a complete example, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: It worked just the way I wanted, thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad it worked! :)

Comment: So I tried to apply the code (last one) to the previous part of my code (I have to read the lines form multiple text files inside a zipped file), but it keeps giving me an index error. Could I be trying to do something that's not possible for the programming language?

Comment: Can you update your question with your full code? It is certainly possible :) I'd say 99.999..% of things are possible in the language :)

Comment: My guess is that either you're calling this function on some set of variables it wasn't meant to be called, or your files don't meet the requirements of this function. Your files need to be strictly chars mixed up with the delimiters you send to the function. If you have a header, or some text, it won't work.

Comment: I've trying to solve the problem for the last couple days, but as I didn't succed I uploaded it as another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69511264/reading-text-files-from-zip-and-writing-it-into-another-text-files